# Liferay Thrift Servlet - standard authentication

Tags: java, servlets, liferay, thrift

i have an Liferay portal 6.2 ce ga4 jboss bundle up and running with a thrift servlet i wrote for communication between an app and the server. I wanna use Liferay for its User Management only, so i just want to authenticate a User with his credentials through the Liferay api.

I first tried to use the UserLocalServiceUtil, but when i call the Method the Server throws this error :

```
08:07:13,962 SEVERE [com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) BeanLocator is null
08:07:13,963 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
08:07:13,963 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1365)
08:07:13,963 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:74)
08:07:13,964 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.getService(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:3417)
08:07:13,964 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.getBeanIdentifier(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:1004)
08:07:13,964 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.implemented.UserAuthenticationHandler.signIn(UserAuthenticationHandler.java:33)
08:07:13,965 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.generated.UserAuthenticationService$Processor$signIn.getResult(UserAuthenticationService.java:253)
08:07:13,965 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.generated.UserAuthenticationService$Processor$signIn.getResult(UserAuthenticationService.java:1)
08:07:13,966 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
08:07:13,966 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
08:07:13,966 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.thrift.server.TServlet.doPost(TServlet.java:83)
08:07:13,967 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
08:07:13,967 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
08:07:13,968 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
08:07:13,968 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
08:07:13,969 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
08:07:13,969 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
08:07:13,970 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
08:07:13,970 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
08:07:13,971 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
08:07:13,971 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
08:07:13,972 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
08:07:13,972 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
08:07:13,972 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
08:07:13,973 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
08:07:13,973 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
08:07:13,974 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.BeanLocatorException: BeanLocator has not been set
08:07:13,974 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate(PortalBeanLocatorUtil.java:82)
08:07:13,974 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.getService(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:3417)
08:07:13,975 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.getBeanIdentifier(UserLocalServiceUtil.java:1004)
08:07:13,975 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.implemented.UserAuthenticationHandler.signIn(UserAuthenticationHandler.java:33)
08:07:13,975 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.generated.UserAuthenticationService$Processor$signIn.getResult(UserAuthenticationService.java:253)
08:07:13,976 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.generated.UserAuthenticationService$Processor$signIn.getResult(UserAuthenticationService.java:1)
08:07:13,976 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
08:07:13,976 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
08:07:13,977 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.thrift.server.TServlet.doPost(TServlet.java:83)
08:07:13,977 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
08:07:13,977 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
08:07:13,977 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
08:07:13,978 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
08:07:13,978 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
08:07:13,978 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
08:07:13,979 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)
08:07:13,980 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
08:07:13,980 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
08:07:13,980 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
08:07:13,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
08:07:13,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
08:07:13,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
08:07:13,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
08:07:13,982 ERROR [stderr] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I really don't come any further. I also looked at com.liferay.portal.security.auth but cannot find any classes. I just want a method that i can call that checks if a user is registered.

Here is my Code that is running on the servlet.

```
import org.apache.thrift.TException;

import com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.generated.User;
import com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.thrift.generated.UserAuthenticationService;
import com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil;

    public class UserAuthenticationHandler implements UserAuthenticationService.Iface {

        @Override
        public User signIn(String forceMail, String password){
            System.out.println("signIn called...");

            User usr = new User();

            System.out.println("returning user:" + usr.toString());

            try {


                int status = com.liferay.portal.service.UserLocalServiceUtil.authenticateByEmailAddress(0, forceMail, password, null,null, null);
                System.out.println("Status : " +status);
                switch(status) {

                    case -1:    return null;

                    case  1:    System.out.println("case 1");
                                com.liferay.portal.model.User liferayUser = UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByEmailAddress(0, forceMail);
                                System.out.println(liferayUser.toString());
                }
                return usr;
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return usr;
        }
```

I have the portal-service.jar included. And here is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>alarm-thrift-servlet</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>ThriftServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ThriftServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.fsu.unired.alarmapp.servlet.ThriftServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ThriftServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ThriftServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're deploying a plain web application - you might want to try a Liferay-web plugin. This is very similar but is aware of Liferay being present and might initialize the infrastructure that Liferay's API needs. Otherwise you'll have to do this initialization yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
But as im trying to create such a project, it says that for such a type of project i need the liferay plugins sdk version 7.0.0 which is, i think, not available on liferays download site.

Comment: For Liferay 6.2 you need the Liferay 6.2 SDK (or the maven artifacts). Version 7 is the next one, still unpublished (pre-alpha), so in order to get those artifacts it's best to get the source and build them yourself. Or check if the milestones come with an SDK - I don't know this from the top of my head